# ImportError: No module named 'mirror'

Tags: python, python-3.3, importerror

I am using Python3.3 and I have installed a package called python-bidi, which can be found [here](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-bidi/).

I have installed the package by running: `python setup.py install`, which was instructed in the package documentation.

Now I am running a code that uses that package but I get this error:

```
File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\python_bidi-0.3.4-py3.3.egg\bidi\algorithm.py", line 24, in <module>
from mirror import MIRRORED
ImportError: No module named 'mirror'
```

However, looking at this folder: `C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\python_bidi-0.3.4-py3.3.egg\bidi` I can see that there is a file called `mirror.py`. 
What is the reason for the error that I get?
Thanks for any help on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Python 2.7, you can do `import bidi.algorithm`, but it will fail in Python 3.3. Actually, it comes from changes in the way modules are imported. Notice the python-bidi library was last updated in 2010.

See [PEP 328](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0328/), which also dates back 2010. This PEP addresses the following issue: *"Imports can be ambiguous in the face of packages; within a package, it's not clear whether import foo refers to a module within the package or some module outside the package. (More precisely, a local module or package can shadow another hanging directly off sys.path.)"*

With the new notation, that is used in Python 3.x, you would write, in "bidi/algorithm.py", `from .mirror import MIRRORED` instead of `from mirror import MIRRORED`. Notice the dot!

The import would work, but the module bidi.algorithm would still fail to load, because of other incompatibilities. Namely, there is at some point `X2_X5_MAPPINGS.keys() + ['BN', 'PDF', 'B']`, which fails because `dict.keys()` does not return a list any longer, but a "dict_keys" object.

Therefore, you won't be able to use this package in Python 3.x, unless you are willing to do some work to resolve incompatibilities.

As a side note, the new notation `from .mirror import MIRRORED` is also understood by Python 2.7, so it should be possible to make python-bidi to be compatible with both Python 2.x and 3.x lines.

Answer (score 1):

The only thing left is to change line 41 and 42 by adding list around `X2_X5_MAPPINGS.keys()` and `X2_X5_MAPPINGS.keys()` to become:

```
list(X2_X5_MAPPINGS.keys())
```

and

```
list(X2_X5_MAPPINGS.keys())
```

and also change line 600 from:

```
if isinstance(unicode_or_str, unicode)
```

to

```
if isinstance(unicode_or_str, str):
```